# How to make a link to all polls in Drupal 7.34?

Tags: drupal, hyperlink

I removed the standard navigation link to the page with all polls (a content type). Now I can seem to get it back anymore. What URL links to a page that shows all recent polls?

Answer (score 0):

Path to list of all available polls is **poll**. (example.com/poll)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I disagree. The question was: "What URL links to a page that shows all recent polls?". "poll" is the answer.

Comment: I am looking for the page that shows the latest, not all available posts. The provided link only shows 1 poll for me.

Comment: Then you need to create your own page, using Views, or write a custom module.